# How to fetch data from console output to table using angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

[image: Error Image]I have a table in HTML, i need to fetch data from consoled output to the table. Please help.
HTML Code:

```
<table class="table">
   <tr>
     <th>Completed On</th>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>ParticipantId</th>
   </tr>
   <tr *ngFor="let data of result">
     <td>{{ data.completedOn }}</td>
     <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ data.participantId }}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

TS Code:
public result:any = [];

```
   this.service
            .getParticipent(comparedCampaign.id,token)
            .subscribe(
                participent => {
                    this.loading = false;
            // this.result = data;
             console.log( this.result);
                    var survey = this.surveyResults;
                    if(participent.length > 0) {
                        var data =[];
              participent.map(function(item) { 
                var list = survey.filter(function(result) {
                    if(result.participantId) {
                        return result.participantId == item.id
                    }
               })
                data.push(list);
                 this.result = data;
                 console.log( this.result);
             })

                        console.log(data);
                    } else {
                        alert('No Participent found!');
                    }
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
    }
}
```

From this i need to fetch CompletedOn, id and participantId to the table

JSON Consoled output:

```
 [[{"satisfaction":"[object Object]","completedOn":"2017-08-22T08:52:55.788Z","id":3,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"price":"less","recomondation":"1","winback":"reason6"},"completedOn":"2017-08-22T09:12:40.800Z","id":4,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"price":"less","recomondation":"1","winback":"reason6"},"completedOn":"2017-08-22T11:36:04.861Z","id":5,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"price":"less","recomondation":"1","winback":"reason6"},"completedOn":"2017-08-22T11:59:24.334Z","id":6,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"price":"medium","customer":"yes","recomondation":"2","sales":["phone","Shop","webshop"],"webVist":"5","shopVist":"5","phoneVist":"5","prodandService":["{product_list}"],"importance":["Service"],"frequence":"quarter","satisfaction":"3"},"completedOn":"2017-08-22T12:20:54.280Z","id":7,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"price":"medium","customer":"no","recomondation":"1","winback":"reason1","winback_quality":"reason2"},"completedOn":"2017-08-22T12:22:43.153Z","id":8,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"prodandService":[{"index":"Orbiz"},{"index":"qwerq"},{"index":"asfd"},{"index":"test"},{"index":"test123"},{"index":"TestWD"},{"index":"IOS app"},{"index":"Lipstick"},{"index":"Foundation"},{"index":"lipstick"},{"index":"Website"},{"index":"App IOS"},{"index":"Shampoo Vanilla"},{"index":"Shampoo Strawberry"},{"index":"car"},"Lipstick"],"price":"medium","customer":"yes","recomondation":"4","sales":["phone"],"phoneVist":"3","importance":["Quality"],"frequence":"quarter","satisfaction":"3"},"completedOn":"2017-08-28T09:39:54.676Z","id":10,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"prodandService":[{"index":"Orbiz"},{"index":"qwerq"},{"index":"asfd"},{"index":"test"},{"index":"test123"},{"index":"TestWD"},{"index":"IOS app"},{"index":"Lipstick"},{"index":"Foundation"},{"index":"lipstick"},{"index":"Website"},{"index":"App IOS"},{"index":"Shampoo Vanilla"},{"index":"Shampoo Strawberry"},{"index":"car"},"Foundation","IOS app","test123","test"],"price":"medium","customer":"yes","recomondation":"5","sales":["visits"],"salesVist":"3","importance":["Quality"],"frequence":"year","satisfaction":"5","knowledge":["IOS app","Foundation","Website"],"development":"littleLess","suppliers":"yes","competators":"60","competators_reasons":"Quality","Need":["{product_list}"],"service":"5","collaboration":"4","continuedCollaboration":"3","improvements":["Service","Price"],"winback":"reason3"},"completedOn":"2017-08-28T14:45:13.991Z","id":11,"participantId":217},{"satisfaction":{"prodandService":[{"index":"Orbiz"},{"index":"qwerq"},{"index":"asfd"},{"index":"test"},{"index":"test123"},{"index":"TestWD"},{"index":"IOS app"},{"index":"Lipstick"},{"index":"Foundation"},{"index":"lipstick"},{"index":"Website"},{"index":"App IOS"},{"index":"Shampoo Vanilla"},{"index":"Shampoo Strawberry"},{"index":"car"},"TestWD","Lipstick"],"price":"less","recomondation":"4","sales":["phone"],"phoneVist":"3","importance":["Quality","Assortment"],"frequence":"quarter","satisfaction":"4","knowledge":["IOS app"],"Need":["TestWD","Lipstick"],"development":"same","suppliers":"yes","competators":"60","competators_reasons":"Assortment","service":"4","collaboration":"4","continuedCollaboration":"3","improvements":["Assortment"],"winback":"reason4"},"completedOn":"2017-09-01T14:23:04.533Z","id":13,"participantId":217}]]
```

with error:
"EXCEPTION: Cannot set property 'result' of undefined"

Please Help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post image showing your error ?

Comment: I had uploaded image, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the 0th index of the array and then assign to the result,

```
this.service.getParticipent(comparedCampaign.id,token).subscribe(
participent => {
   this.result = participent[0];
}
```

then you can iterate over and display as you mentioned above,

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of result">
      <td>{{ data.completedOn }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.participantId }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: no, i must get all the 3 data in JSON output inside table

Comment: i got this error "ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'"

Comment: Create an array, or transform to object in your component.

Comment: i am not getting, i am very new to this, please help

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are showing array in wrong format so try this

```
this.service.getParticipent(comparedCampaign.id,token).subscribe(
participent => {
   this.result = participent;
}
```

and use your array like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of result">
      <td>{{ data?.completedOn }}</td>
      <td>{{ data?.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ data?.participantId }}</td>
 </tr>
```

also please try to print whole array in HTML too, for better understanding like this

```
{{result | json}}
```

Comment: it is jus giving me id

Comment: please try my Updated answer

Comment: Ya i will try and update, i feel i am wrong in writing ngfor in HTML

Comment: no, your `*ngFor` is with right syntax, but seems like you array is not in format, that is why i am asking for print in HTML

Comment: i am getting result of undefined error so i have done like this

Comment: var survey = this.surveyResults;
         if(participent.length > 0) {
          var data =[];
              participent.map(function(item) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                var list = survey.filter(function(result) {
                    if(result.participantId) {
                        return result.participantId == item.id
                    }
               })
                data.push(list);
                 this.result = data;

             })
              },50)

Comment: this is tough to read please Update your question, else try to reproduce same problem on plunker.

Comment: Sorry what i did is wrong, i am getting error saying, "result is undefined"

Comment: remove `var` whereever you used, also try method suggested in my answer, btw in which line you are getting this error ? post related code